# Pass bash variables to a list of commands stored as a separate "commands.txt"

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I have the following PBS script:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#PBS -l walltime=12:00:00,nodes=1:ppn=24,pmem=2580mb

((start=24))
((n_jobs_procimg=8))

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
conda activate msi_sip_37

module load parallel
parallel -u -j 3 < commands.txt
wait
```

And the contents of commands.txt are:

```
python runs/process_img.py --n_jobs $n_jobs_procimg --msi_test True --idx_min $start+0 --idx_max $start+8
python runs/process_img.py --n_jobs $n_jobs_procimg --msi_test True --idx_min $start+8 --idx_max $start+16
python runs/process_img.py --n_jobs $n_jobs_procimg --msi_test True --idx_min $start+16 --idx_max $start+24
```

I [incorrectly] expect that `$start` and `$n_jobs_procimg` should be available to the commands in *commands.txt*, but when I run this job, I get the following error for each command in *commands.txt*:

```
usage: process_img.py [-h] [-n N_JOBS] [-m MSI_TEST] [-i IDX_MIN] [-d IDX_MAX]
process_img.py: error: argument -n/--n_jobs: expected one argument
```

**How do I modify the `parallel` command in the PBS script so that `$start` and `$n_jobs_procimg` are passed to *commands.txt*?**

In this case, `$start` should be an integer equal to 24 and `$n_jobs_procimg` should be an integer equal to 8.

It's not relevant to my question, but for context the *process_img.py* script uses a multiprocessing pool that takes the number of processing cores and as an argument (`--n_jobs`), and I want to have control over that based on the total number of processing cores I have available.

Comment: The final `wait` seems unnecessary. Is there something more in the script you are not telling us? `-u` is almost always not what you want. Compare `--group`, `--linebuffer` and `--ungroup`.

Comment: Yes, one more command that just transfers data to another directory. I omitted it in this example because it's irrelevant, but here it is: `python runs/transfer_data_level.py`. The `-u` was added because I found it was the only variable that would print my output in reasonable amount of time. It's for testing only, and I wouldn't think would change anything by omitting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`export` the variables:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#PBS -l walltime=12:00:00,nodes=1:ppn=24,pmem=2580mb

start=24
n_jobs_procimg=8
export start
export n_jobs_procimg

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
conda activate msi_sip_37

module load parallel
parallel -u -j 3 < commands.txt
```

Comment: This does the trick, thanks! When using `export` in this way, will the variables persist after this session? My thought is no, but can you confirm?

Comment: They die when the shell dies.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the two constants in a separate script:

constants.sh:

```
((start=24))
((n_jobs_procimg=8)
```

Then use source:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#PBS -l walltime=12:00:00,nodes=1:ppn=24,pmem=2580mb

source constants.sh

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
conda activate msi_sip_37

module load parallel
parallel -u -j 3 < commands.txt
wait
```

And then use the commands.txt to include that as well:

```
source constants.sh
python runs/process_img.py --n_jobs $n_jobs_procimg --msi_test True --idx_min $start+0 --idx_max $start+8
python runs/process_img.py --n_jobs $n_jobs_procimg --msi_test True --idx_min $start+8 --idx_max $start+16
python runs/process_img.py --n_jobs $n_jobs_procimg --msi_test True --idx_min $start+16 --idx_max $start+24
```

That way, you have them available everywhere and only need to edit one file if there are changes.

Comment: Hmm, not working for me. I added `echo n_jobs_procimg` as a command right after `source constants.sh` in commands.txt, and it doesn't print anything as output (just a blank line). This leads me to believe either `source constants.sh` isn't initializing the variables or they are initialized but I have the wrong syntax in commands.txt for accessing them (using `$n_jobs_procimg`).

Comment: To provide more information,`$start` and `$n_jobs_procimg` are available in the PBS script (i.e., `echo $start` prints `24` to the output. However, I do not get this same behavior after calling `source constants.sh` from commands.txt. Perhaps this is something to do with scope or PATH variable?

Comment: Weird, I have a setup of about 100 scripts which work that way.
Exporting both variables is the better way, see above.